# SPARK parallelization of algorithm - non-typical, how to

Tags: apache-spark

I have a processing requirement that does not seem to fit the nice SPARK parallelization use cases. On the other hand, I may not see how it can be done in SPARK easily.

I am seeking the easiest way to parallelize the following situation:

1. Given a set of N records of record type A,

   2. perform some processing on A records that generates a not yet existing set of initial results, say, of J records of record type B. Record type B has a data range aspect to it.

      3. Then repeat the process for the A set of records not yet processed - the leftovers - for any records generated as part of B, but look to the left and to the right of the A records.

         4. Repeat 3 until no new records generated.

This may sound odd, but it is nothing more than taking a set of trading records, and deciding for a given computed period Pn, if there is a bull or bear spread evident during this period. Once that initial period is found, then date-wise before Pn and after Pn, one can attempt to look for a bull or bear spread period that precedes or follows the initial Pn period. And so on. It all works correctly.

The algorithm I designed works on inserting records using SQL and some looping. The records generated do not exist initially and get created on the fly. I looked at dataframes and RDDs, but it is not so evident (to me) how one would do this.

Using SQL it is not such a difficult algorithm, but you need to work through the records of a given logical key set sequentially. Thus not a typical SPARK use case.

My questions are then:

1. How can I achieve at the very least parallelization?
2. Should we use mapPartitions in some way so as to at least get ranges of logical key sets to process, or is this simply not possible given the use case I attempt to present? I am going to try this, but feel I may be barking up the wrong tree here. It may just need to be a loop / while in the driver running single thread.

Some examples record A's shown in tabular format - as per how this algorithm works:

```
         Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May  Jun  Jul   Aug  Sep
key X     -5    1     0    10     9    -20   0    5    7
```

would result in record B's being **generated** as follows:

```
key X    Jan - Feb  --> Bear
key X    Apr - Jun  --> Bull
```

Comment: Can we insert to a temp view from a func that is mapPartitioned? I think so based on a single example elsewhere.

Comment: Disregard the previous comment - certainly not the same tempview and realized that we can not do an INSERT as in SQL to such a construct, but via UNION of DFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This falls into the category of non-typical Spark. Solved via looping within a loop in Spark Scala but with JDBC usage. Could as well have been a Scala JDBC program. Also variation with foreachPartition.